# How to fetch top ten rows of different tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle, select, oracle12c

I have 4 tables which have 5 columns in common. I want to fetch the latest overall top ten rows for these tables, and retrieve them.
How can i do that?
I tried using a simple join command, but instead of 5 columns I get 20 columns! each table has its own column name alias! but what I want is, to have a 5 column table which contains all of those top 10s.

Update:

```
fetch FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Command returns the 10 first records, not the latest ones
when I run the following command for example :

```
select * from tblTest order by ID FETCH First 3 ROWS Only;
```

I get

```
1 Ali
2 Jacob
3 Chris
```

Where I actually needed

```
18 Fatima
19 Mary
20 Catherina
```

How can i achieve such a thing?

Comment: Just to make sure - do you want the overall top 10 rows, or the top 10 of each table?

Comment: I want the overall top 10 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle 12c, you can use the `TOP-N` query :

```
SQL> select * from(
  2  (select deptno from emp
  3  ORDER BY deptno
  4  fetch FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)
  5  UNION all
  6  (select deptno from emp
  7  ORDER BY deptno
  8  fetch FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)
  9  )
 10  /

    DEPTNO
----------
        10
        10
        10
        20
        20
        20
        20
        20
        30
        30
        10

    DEPTNO
----------
        10
        10
        20
        20
        20
        20
        20
        30
        30

20 rows selected.
```

Unlike `ROWNUM`, you need not worry about the `ORDER`.

**Update** Regarding last records in the order

Use `DESC` in order.

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM(
  3    (SELECT deptno FROM emp ORDER BY deptno DESC
  4    FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
  5    )
  6  UNION ALL
  7    (SELECT deptno FROM emp ORDER BY deptno DESC
  8    FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
  9    ) )
 10  /

    DEPTNO
----------
        30
        30
        30
        30
        30
        30

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Do you need the last records in the order? If yes, use `DESC` in order. See my update in answer.

Comment: Thanks but that would give me records in the form of 20,19,18 order, while i want it to be 18,19,20.

Comment: Add `order by ASC` to this result set in outer query. So, 20,19,18 will be ordered in ascending order as 18,19,20. Please mark it answered if this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union all` to get all the rows consecutively, and then take the top 10:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM   (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
        FROM    (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table1
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table2
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table3
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table4)
        ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
WHERE   rownum <= 10
```

Comment: doesn't it have a bad impact on database? i mean wouldnt 4 individual selects be better?

Comment: If you want the database to filter the top ten results, it has to be in a single query. It is worth noting, however, that any row in the overall top ten must be in its own top table's top 10 too. It may be worth adding this filtering to each individual query, but you'l have to benchmark it with your own data to see if it improves performance or not.